# Sql Query Receive name instead of ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making an query in which I want to see the total reserves that the client has ...
The problem is that I get the client ID ... and not the client name as desired. Someone can help me?

**My current query**

```
Select Reserva.ID_Cliente, count (Reserva.ID_Reserva) 
From Reserva 
left outer join Cliente 
on Reserva.ID_Reserva = Cliente.ID_Cliente 
group by Reserva.ID_Cliente
```

I remember that with this query I get the client ID ... but I wanted to receive the Client Name and not the ID.

In the reservation table I only have client ID and not the name, otherwise I would select the name and not the ID.

Comment: You are selecting the ID. That is why you get the ID.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be joining by Reserva.ID_Cliente ? Anyway, just add what you need it in the Group By:

```
Select Cliente.Name, count(Reserva.ID_Reserva) 
From Reserva left outer join Cliente on Reserva.ID_Cliente = Cliente.ID_Cliente group by Reserva.ID_Cliente, Cliente.Name
```

Comment: Works !! Thank you for helping you with the rest of the users who promptly helped me! Greetings to all

Answer (score 3):

Note: You are using a left join, meaning a reserve might not have a corresponding Client.

```
Select Cliente.ClienteName, count (Reserva.ID_Reserva) 
From Reserva 
left outer join Cliente on Reserva.ID_Reserva = Cliente.ID_Cliente 
group by Reserva.ID_Cliente, Cliente.ClienteName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Select 
    isnull(Cliente.Name, 'Name missing'), 
    count (Reserva.ID_Reserva) 
From Reserva 
left outer join Cliente 
on Reserva.ID_Reserva = Cliente.ID_Cliente 
group by Cliente.Name, Reserva.ID_Cliente
```

This assumes that the table `Cliente` contains the name field. The left join does not help! as mentioned elsewhere

UPDATE
I've added the left join back in and also included a null check on the name. As mentioned, this assumes a reservation without a matching client.

Comment: is it close to what I want ... but when executing the query ... it does not appear any value to me ... it should have vr with the inner join

Comment: Try posting the table structures and, possibly, some sample data

Comment: @Dinho, you wouldn't want to group by name but ID. ID is unique but name might not be, no?